# Java multiple array declaration

Tags: java, arrays

The statement

```
int[] a
```

is the same as

```
int a[]
```

However, what happens when you have multiple declarations in a single line?

What is the difference between

```
int[] a, b, c
```

and

```
int a[], b, c
```

Does the first one declare three arrays, and in the second they are `int`s, but `a` is an array?

EDIT:

Why does the declaration happen that way?

Is this a good reason to use the syntax `int[] a` rather than `int a[]`?

Comment: `Does the first one declare three arrays, and in the second they are ints, but a is an array?` Did you try it?

Comment: @Cruncher I don't think this is an appropriate comment here. The question is legitimate and trying it doesn't really explains why it is so and how such declarations work.

Comment: @sashkello the questions asks **if** it is so, not **why** it is so.

Comment: @Cruncher Sorry, I'll update my question to reflect the intent better.

Comment: As I understand it, the first declares three arrays while the second declares an array and two ints.  Because there be dragons, I never use comma-separated declarations but instead put everything on separate lines.

Comment: @Cruncher It doesn't prevent you from writing a good answer about it. It is implied that OP doesn't understand how it works and wants to know it. Don't be negative in your comments - I don't think mocking user does any good whatsoever.

Comment: I prefer to use `int[] a` vs `int a[]`, as it's more intuitive and less error-prone.

Comment: @sashkello it caused him to update, and write a more meaningful and helpful question. No one is mocking here. I would say that good has been done. I would go a step further actually, and assert in the question that it is true. And THEN ask why.

Comment: @Cruncher I think comments are to be constructive, that's all. If you think the question can be improved, say how. If you think it's beyond saving, explain why and vote to close. I'm just saying this is not a bad question and deserves to be improved and answered. There are plenty of other questions where "did you try it?" is really all you can say... I don't believe this is one of those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answers cover the what pretty well, but I will try to explain why that happens. Basically, the compiler interprets

```
XXXXXX a, b, c;
```

as

```
XXXXXX a;
XXXXXX b;
XXXXXX c;
```

no matter what `XXXXXX` is. So in your examples,

```
int[] a, b, c;
```

turns into

```
int[] a;
int[] b;
int[] c;
```

and

```
int a[], b, c;
```

turns into

```
int a[];
int b;
int c;
```

Answer (score 4):

from the [JLS Chapter 10.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.2):

The [] may appear as part of the type at the beginning of the declaration, or as part of the declarator for a particular variable, or both.

For example:

```
byte[] rowvector, colvector, matrix[];
```

This declaration is equivalent to:

```
byte rowvector[], colvector[], matrix[][];
```

Comment: But they're not equivalent to `byte rowvector[], colvector, matrix[]'`

Comment: True, but to me, that seems to follow logically from the example shown.

Comment: "Logic" is a tricky thing.  In your example, yes, but it's not so obvious with `int a[], b, c;`

Comment: Essentially, that is the same example, but I suppose it is less obvious. I like @quazzieclodo's answer. It makes it very clear.

Answer (score 2):

The first one declares three arrays, the second one a single array and two ints. (see Java Language Specification for Java 7, §10.2)

Answer (score 2):

```
int[] a, b, c
```

will create 3 arrays named a, b, and c.

```
int a[], b, c
```

will create an array of integers in a, and two single integer variables b, and c.

Answer (score 1):

```
static int[] a, b, c;
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(a + ", " + b + ", " + c);
}
```

Output: `null, null, null`

using `static int a[], b, c;`

Output: `null, 0, 0`

Answer (score 0):

```
int a, b, c, d, e = 4;
```

is declaring 5 ints but only initialising 'e'.

In the same way,

```
int[] a, b, c, d, e = new int[4];
```

will only initialise e.

You'd need something like

```
int[] a=new int[4], b=new int[4], etc...
```

which frankly, isn't worth one-lining...